# MySql use INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE in production

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

In our application we are about to introduce tagging to various entities. I read about possible solutions and found this series of blog posts:

- http://howto.philippkeller.com/2005/04/24/Tags-Database-schemas/
- http://howto.philippkeller.com/2005/05/05/Tags-with-MySQL-fulltext/
- http://howto.philippkeller.com/2005/06/19/Tagsystems-performance-tests/

Based on this I'm thinking about to introduce fulltext indexing on our "tags" columns. So far so good (knowing the limits of fulltext index such as stopwords, tokenization separators, etc).

However, we need to be able to list the existing tags in some cases, and we require that tags defined by different users are hidden from each other (basically if 'user A' defines tag "private" then 'user B' should not see it).

I found a possible solution that seems to work, however, I'm not convinced. This is what I currently do:

- `SET GLOBAL innodb_ft_aux_table=''` to the name of the table
- run `SELECT DISTINCT WORD tag, COUNT(1) cnt FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE WHERE DOCID IN (?,?) GROUP BY tag ORDER BY cnt DESC` (the `DOCID` list is prefiltered by user permissions - the result set is expected to be lower than a few thousand records, mostly below 100)

I can also extend the `WHERE` part of the select to filter the result list (for autocomplete purposes). **But**, since this approach uses a global variable, it is not safe to use in concurrent environment. I can apply some kind of synchronization but **should I at all use this table**? Also, since this table is categorized as "monitoring" by mysql documentation I'm not sure this is a proper use-case. If not, what other solutions do I have with fulltext index?

Comment: It took me some time to understand what your underlying problem is: you want to store tags in a denormalized way (several tags in one field). Don't. Nothing good will come from it. If you think you need all tags in one field (or need other advice), describe what problem/requirements you want to solve with that design, and we may be able to propose a different solution. You want to solve a problem you don't need to have by a hackish solution that probably raises more problems than it solves. Also be aware that the blog post has been written 15(!!!) years ago.

Comment: Okay, a bit more info about the requirements: we need to provide a tagging solution for users on various entities, so that they can group various items flexibly. Tags will only be used to filter lists (no special operators needed). Users also should be able to list their tags (and only theirs). Speed is not an issue (number of records is relatively low). A simple solution is preferred, therefore, the denormalized storage and the fulltext index is a strightforward implementation - up to the point we need to list the tags in use.

Comment: The straightforward approach is an object-tag table like `objectid, tagid`. One row per tag. Not doing this makes every otherwise trivial operation on tags more complicated: renaming or deleting a tag completely (no foreign key possible), editing the tags for an object (e.g. removing a tag requires string operations and adding a tag additionally needs to check if a tag is already assigned to that object), counting how many tags an object has, finding the most popular tag/tag usage counts, ...

Comment: Thanks. You pointed me to the right direction: further clarify requirements. Seems like fulltext index is not the way to go.